# Smooth CSS 'collapse' transition on width, padding and border

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a transition that will effectively 'collapse' a div and floating elements that it contains, by altering the width, padding and border.

I have done some investigation which you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/p38b6ndb/1

To include a sample:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="sub-section">label</div>
        <div class="sub-section">field</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section collapsible">
        <div class="sub-section">label</div>
        <div class="sub-section">field</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="sub-section">label</div>
        <div class="sub-section">field</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.section.collapsible {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity linear 1s, width linear 1s;
}

.section.collapsible.collapsed {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.sub-section {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
}
```

**The scenario:** the 2nd section should collapse, with the 3rd section moving left alongside the 1st section.

**The problem:** if I have `padding` and/or `border` on the div that is being collapsed, when the width reaches a certain amount on collapse the divs wrap around, causing the height to increase, pushing subsequent elements downwards.

- I tried with `box-sizing: border-box` but this has a clear wrapping
  effect as well.
- I tried to transition the `padding` and `border-width` as well as the
  `width`, but again it still wraps. I could experiment with different
  durations but it still has a strange effect.
- I tried to ignore the padding and border as they go opaque, and just 
  add a `margin-left`, but this doesn't affect the height and the
  'pushing downwards'.
- I could fix the height but I actually want height to be auto as each 
  section could contain various sizes of content.

How can I implement this collapse transition on divs with padded/bordered elements?

If an answer could be demonstrated by updating the fiddle that would be really welcome.

Comment: Why not transition the font-size to 0 as well? - http://jsfiddle.net/p38b6ndb/2/

Comment: Good idea, this works and doesn't result in content being pushed downwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best solution I have found is to transition padding and border-width to 0, but only for the left and right, not for the top and bottom. That way, the collapse appears only to be on the width, the divs do not change height at all.

```
.section.collapsible {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity linear 1s, width linear 1s;
}

.section.collapsible.collapsed {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.section.collapsible .sub-section {    
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 2px;
    transition: padding linear 1s, border-width linear 1s;
}

.section.collapsible.collapsed .sub-section {    
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-width: 2px 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p38b6ndb/6/

This also means I can still use `box-sizing: border-box` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set 'padding: 0' to each .collapsed > sub-section-border-box, and of course set a transition

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h1ww6psj/)

```
.section.collapsible .sub-section-border-box {    
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 2px;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}

.section.collapsible.collapsed .sub-section-border-box{    
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: So based on the 3 examples in the demo, this is the combination of the 'sub-section-border-box' version with the transition to padding:0 and border-width:0 of the 'sub-section-padding' version. This is definitely better as it doesn't push down content below, however the content shrinking in height like that means it might even be less desirable than the 'sub-section-border-box' version which just transitions straight across.